# Java - Add Swing component at Runtime WITH a reference name?

Tags: java, swing, reference, runtime

I am currently working on an app that adds JTextFields to a panel at runtime using:

```
int rowCounter = 1;             
pnlRows.add(new JLabel("Row " + rowCounter));
pnlRows.add(new JTextField(20));
pnlRows.revalidate();
validate();
```

The problem i have is that i want to use their values in a method but have no way of referencing them.

Is there a way to do something along the lines of:

```
int i = 1;
JTextField row + i = new JTextField();
i++;
```

So that every time i run the TextField made will be called row1, row2, row3 respectively.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't, what you need to do is add them to a list so that later you can get them all.

Somewhere in your class you need this:

```
List<JTextField> fields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
```

Then when they add them you can do this:

```
int rowCounter = fields.size()+1;             
pnlRows.add(new JLabel("Row " + rowCounter));
JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
pnlRows.add(field);
fields.add(field);
pnlRows.revalidate();
validate();
```

Then finally wne you want to get them all you can iterate the list and get all the text fields out one by one.

```
for(JTextField field : fields){
    dostuff ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public List<JTextField> rows = new Linkedlist<JTextField>();

addRow() {
    JTextField field = new JTextField(20);
    rows.add(field);
    pnlRows.add(new JLabel("Row " + rows.size()));
    pnlRows.add(field);
    pnlRows.revalidate();
    validate();
}
```

Comment: This is good, although you don't need to call revalidate() + validate(). revalidate() alone is enough.

Comment: why a *linked* list? It's almost never the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible. Another (and perhaps neater) way to do this is to store the Labels when you create them something like

```
JTextField label = new JTextField(20);
fieldList.add(label);
pnlRows.add(label);
```

You can then use the fieldList to access the text fields you want:

```
JTextField label = fieldList.get(row);
```

Edit: fieldList is a

```
List<JTextField>
```

of course.